# Proving $f : \Bbb R \to S^1 , f (t) = e^{2iπt}$ is an open map.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\}$. Consider the map $f : \Bbb R \to S^1 , f (t) = e^{2iπt} = \cos(2πt) + i \sin(2πt).$

The map $f$ is onto and continuous. I was reading an online lecture note about proving $f$ is an open map and came across the following observation.

> For every $x \in \Bbb R$ and $\varepsilon < \frac 12$ , the image $f(x
>  − \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$ is the intersection of an open
>   half-plane with the unit circle $S ^1$ .

I'm having trouble understanding the above statement. The definition of open-half plane found on [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-Plane.html) is

> A half-plane is a planar region consisting of all points on one side
>   of an infinite straight line, and no points on the other side.
>
> If the points on the line are included, then it is called an closed
>   half-plane. If the points on the line are not included, then it is
>   called an **open half-plane**.

But I cannot understand the importance of  $\varepsilon$ to be less than  $\frac12$ and the comment about $f(x
 − \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon).$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to draw a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\nu)=e^{2\pi i\nu}$ and identify $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$. Our goal is to show $f(\theta-\epsilon,\theta+\epsilon)$ is the intersection of an open half plane and the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$. Assume $\theta=0$. Then we can see that $$f\left(-\epsilon,\epsilon\right)=\{e^{2\pi i\nu}\in\mathbb{S}^1:|\nu|<\epsilon\}\subset \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x>\cos(2\pi\epsilon)\}\cap \mathbb{S}^1$$
since $\Re [e^{2\pi i \nu}]=\cos(2\pi \nu)>\cos(2\pi\epsilon)$ for all $|\nu|<\epsilon(<\frac{1}{2})$. Since $H=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x>\cos(2\pi\epsilon)\}$ is an open half plane, this proves the claim for $\theta=0$. Now, let $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary and $R_\theta$ be the rotation of angle $2\pi \theta$. Then $R_\theta$ is an isometric homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also $R_\theta$ maps $H$ to some open half plane $H_\theta$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ to itself. Thus it holds
$$
f(\theta-\epsilon,\theta+\epsilon) = R_\theta\left(f\left(-\epsilon,\epsilon\right)\right)\subset H_\theta \cap \mathbb{S}^1.
$$ This shows the claim for general $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why did you take  $x>\cos(2\pi\epsilon)$?

Comment: An open half plane is given by $\{(x,y)\;|\;l(x,y)>\alpha\}$ for some linear functional $l(x,y)$ and scalar $\alpha$. In this case, $l(x,y)=x$ and $\alpha = \cos(2\pi\epsilon)$.

Comment: Still I cannot see how you arrived at  $x>\cos(2\pi\epsilon)$. Why not $x<\cos(2\pi\epsilon)$ or something? Also you assumed  $x=0$. Can you clarify the notations please?

Comment: @ThomasShelby I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. One last doubt : are we using the fact that  $\cos x $ is a decreasing function on $[0,\pi/2] $?

Comment: Yes, sure. Actually, not only on $[0,\pi/2]$ but also on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $f(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)=f(x-\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$ has a pair of antipodal points on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Thus by the definition of closed-half plane, $f(x-\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$ is intersection of a closed half-plane with the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ due to the antipodal points. I hope this is clear.